# Gmap.Net save image around selected marker

Tags: gmap.net

I have an application with GMap.Net showing various markers.  I know how to take a screen shot of the current map and markers:

```
Dim sImageName As String = DateTime.Now.ToString(Format("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss")) & ".png"
Dim ThisMap As New Bitmap(Form2.myMap.Width, Form2.myMap.Height)
Form2.myMap.DrawToBitmap(ThisMap, New Rectangle(0, 0, Form2.myMap.Width, Form2.myMap.Height))
ThisMap.Save(sImagesFolder & sImageName)
```

What I would like to do is create an image for a selected marker.  Instead of the image being the entire map shown on screen, it would center on the marker and show 100 pixels in each direction.

Does anyone know how to do that?

This is what I tried, but it gives me a blank image-- nothing shows up.  I feel like this should be working...

```
Private Sub MyMap_OnMarkerClick(item As GMapMarker, e As Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles myMap.OnMarkerClick

  SelMarkerX = e.X
  SelMarkerY = e.Y

  Dim sImageName As String = DateTime.Now.ToString(Format("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss")) & ".png"
  Dim ThisMap As New Bitmap(140,100)
  myMap.DrawToBitmap(ThisMap, New Rectangle(SelMarkerX - 70, SelMarkerY - 50, 140, 100))
  ThisMap.Save(sImagesFolder & sImageName)

End Sub
```

I just don't get it. If I write:

```
myMap.DrawToBitmap(ThisMap, New Rectangle(0, 0, 140, 100)
```

then I get what you might expect.  I get the upper left corner of the existing map from 0 to 140 horizontally and 0 to 100 vertically.  If I change it to this:

```
myMap.DrawToBitmap(ThisMap, New Rectangle(10, 0, 140, 100)
```

then I get 0 to 130 horizontally and not 10 to 140.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I couldn't figure out how to do it with Gmap, so I wondered if I could crop it outside of Gmap and apparently that is common.  Here is the code I used.

Dim ThisMap As New Bitmap(Form2.myMap.Width, Form2.myMap.Height)
        Form2.myMap.DrawToBitmap(ThisMap, New Rectangle(0, 0, Form2.myMap.Width, Form2.myMap.Height))
        ThisMap.Save(sImagesFolder & sImageName)

```
    Dim LocX = SelMarkerX - 160 'x cord. of where crop starts
    Dim LocY = SelMarkerY - 120 'y  cord. of where crop starts
    Dim CropW = 320 'Crop width
    Dim CropH = 240 'Crop height
    Dim CropRect As New Rectangle(LocX, LocY, CropW, CropH)

    Dim OriginalImage = ThisMap
    Dim CropImage = New Bitmap(CropRect.Width, CropRect.Height)
    Using grp = Graphics.FromImage(CropImage)
        grp.DrawImage(OriginalImage, New Rectangle(0, 0, CropRect.Width, CropRect.Height), CropRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
        CropImage.Save(sImagesFolder & sImageName)
    End Using
```